# Traduction de "phrase or sentence"

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, science

> Define system, boundary, adiabatic boundary, diathermal boundary, environment, heat, state variables, and equation of state with a **phrase or sentence**.

How should I interprète *phrase or sentence* in order to be understood ?

> Définir le système, la frontière, la frontière adiabatique, la frontière diathermane, l'environnement, la chaleur, les variables d'état et l'équation d'état avec une phrase ou une....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The French *phrase* means sentence while the English "phrase" can be translated by *expression*, *proposition*, *tournure*, *énoncé* and various other words, depending on the context.

You might then write:

> Définir le système, la frontière, la frontière adiabatique, la frontière diathermane, l'environnement, la chaleur, les variables d'état et l'équation d'état en quelques mots ou une phrase complète.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about English, in linguistics a phrase is a part of a sentence, which can amongst others be used for answering. So in :"When are you coming?" "In winter/at 3 pm", the latter are prepositional phrases. In French the linguistic term is "syntagme".